# Image processing: road extraction

Tags: python, opencv

I want to visualize the last kilometer of a cycling race. currently i have tried to do this through canny and contours, but i am not getting the desired result. Someone an idea to make this work? I want to visualize the road between the barriers. I want to detect the four corners of the road to implement homography transform.
[image of road](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MUnM.jpg)

[image: new image containing four corners]
[image after canny and mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSCXB.png)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is using `line-detector`

- 1. Apply `Canny` as a preprocessing method:

  ```py
  import cv2

  img = cv2.imread("road.jpg")
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)
  ```

  Result:

  [image]

  But there is a problem, as you can see the lines other than barriers are also detected:

  [image]

  If we set a `_length_threshold` we can remove most part:

  ```py
  lines = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector(_length_threshold=50).detect(canny)
  ```

  [image]

  Of course, you can test with different `_length_threshold` values.

  But the upper and downward lines still remain. We need vertical lines.

  The vertical line should be `y2 - y1 > 0`. Since if `y2-y1=0` then the line is horizontal:

  ```py
  if abs(current_y2 - current_y1) > 5:
       cv2.line(img,
                pt1=(current_x1, current_y1),
                pt2=(current_x2, current_y2),
                color=(0, 255, 0),
                thickness=3)
  ```

  Result:

  [image]

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("road.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)

lines = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector(_length_threshold=50).detect(canny)

for current_line in lines:
    current_x1 = int(current_line[0][0])
    current_y1 = int(current_line[0][1])
    current_x2 = int(current_line[0][2])
    current_y2 = int(current_line[0][3])

    if abs(current_y2 - current_y1) > 5:
        cv2.line(img,
                 pt1=(current_x1, current_y1),
                 pt2=(current_x2, current_y2),
                 color=(0, 255, 0),
                 thickness=3)

cv2.imwrite("result.png", img)
```

Now, you know the coordinates, you can select the road area.

```py
cv2.rectangle(img, pt1=(600, 70), pt2=(1150, 890), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I have already tried something like this. but this does not get the desired result. First I want to get the four corners of the road and then apply homomorphic transform, so that every frame of the video has the same camera angle. The intention is that if the road contains turns it will also be registered. But maybe this is not practically feasible? I added a new photo to the question to make it clearer